# Add word using sed to the last column of csv

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, while-loop

I tried the following sed and even I have set $ to set the path at the end it doesn't seem to be working. Also I dont know if there's any way of execute this line by line with a **while or for**:

```
sed -E 's/$/Location/'
```

But the ouput i recive is:

```
Locationi,d,nm,yr,dt,mnn,rmd,g,gnr,rc,ct,st,sgns,tt,fl,cmr,lng,lt,gcdng
Location,2018,2018-10-25,sh,vhcl,28,M,B,St. Ls,MO,F,attack,flng,False,-90.219,38.773,True
```

Input

```
 wi,d,nm,yr,dt,mnn,rmd,g,gnr,rc,ct,st,sgns,tt,fl,cmr,lng,lt,gcdng
 2,4141,Armond,2018,2018-10-25,sh,vhcl,28,M,B,St. Ls,MO,F,attack,flng,False,-90.219,38.773,True
```

Ouput expected

```
wi,d,nm,yr,dt,mnn,rmd,g,gnr,rc,ct,st,sgns,tt,fl,cmr,lng,lt,gcdng
2,4141,Armond,2018,2018-10-25,sh,vhcl,28,M,B,St. Ls,MO,F,attack,flng,False,-90.219,38.773,True Location
```

Comment: `sed 's/.*/& Location/' `

Answer (score 0):

If you have the example file ex.csv containing a header-row and 3 data-rows like this:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

So you du the *replacement* from row 2 and onward to avoid the header. This is the `2,$` part.

Then you do the search and replace at the end of each row. `s/$/ Location/`

Put it all together as:

```
$ sed '2,$s/$/ Location/' ex.csv 
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3 Location
4,5,6 Location
7,8,9 Location
```

Comment: Hello

I want to put this "location" text on 2nd column(assuming it is comma separated) on each row?